# "Сбежать с тюрьмы" или "Сбежать из тюрьмы"?

Tags: другое

Я прочитал правило, в котором говорится, что употребляется такой предлог, который указан в приставке.

**До**стучаться **до** небес. Вот тут все понятно. Получается, правильно так: сбежать с тюрьмы? Или как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Семантическая соотносительность предлога и приставки возможна, но не обязательна, так как предлоги и приставки в русском языке многозначны.

Приставка С в глаголе "сбежать" имеет значение удаления посредством действия, названного мотивирующим глаголом, а предлог С имеет значение удаления с ПОВЕРХНОСТИ предмета, в нашем же случае мы имеем удаление ИЗНУТРИ предмета (из тюрьмы), и эту семантику важно обозначить.

В то же время можно сбежать с урока - здесь соотношение значений предлога и приставки соблюдается, так ка урок мыслится как отвлеченный предмет.

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо.